# Yii 2 search in 2 many to many relation

Tags: php, yii2

I have these models :

```
class Article extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    .....

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])->viaTable('rel_tag_article', ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }

}

class News extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    .....

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])->viaTable('rel_tag_news', ['news_id' => 'id']);
    }

}

class Tag extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    .....

    public function getRelTagArticles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RelTagArticle::className(), ['tag_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getRelTagNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RelTagNews::className(), ['tag_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

And in the controller

```
class ArticleController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionArticle($id_article)
    {


    $article = User::find($id_article);

    ...... here ....


    return $this->render('article');
    }

}
```

Under `...here...` I have to find the news that have common tags with my actual article. What is the right way?

Comment: better make it with request. Something like `SELECT * FROM rel_tag_article t
INNER JOIN rel_tag_news t1 ON t.id=t1.id
WHERE t.article_id=123 ` should work

Answer (score 0):

## You can use article active record to get tags and in turn use tags to get news ##

```
   class ArticleController extends \yii\web\Controller
    {
      public function actionArticle($id_article)
      {              
        $article = User::find($id_article);
        $tags=$article->tags;
        $related_news=array();
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
          $related_news=array_merge($tag->getRelTagNews(),$related_news);
        }

        return $this->render('related_news');
      }        
    }
```

[Visit this yii2 page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation-in-yii-2-0/)